# Unable to fetch value from the service inside the controller

Tags: angularjs

I just want to fetch the value of movies variable in the controller "Data Controller". Below is my code snippet for app.js:

```
myApp.service('datatransfer', ['$http', function($http)
        {
            var service = this;
            var movies;
            service.getMovies = function()
            {
                $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/54jf7').success(function(data)
                {
                    movies = data;
                });
                return movies;
            };  
        }]);

        myApp.controller('DataController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'datatransfer', function($scope, $http, $location, datatransfer)
            {
                $scope.loaded = false;
                datatransfer.getMovies().then(function(data)
                {
                    $scope.movies = data;
                    $scope.loaded = true;
                });
                $location.path('/home');
            }]);
```

From service "datatransfer", it is returning the correct value of movies but when the service is injected to controller and getMovies() is used, then it gives the below error. It is unable to take up the value being returned by the getMovies().

```
angular.js:13642 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> (app.js:47)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4708)
    at P.instance (angular.js:10177)
    at n (angular.js:9096)
    at g (angular.js:8459)
    at g (angular.js:8462)
    at angular.js:8339
    at angular.js:1782
    at m.$eval (angular.js:17378)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:17478)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the http request from the service

```
 myApp.service('datatransfer', ['$http', function($http) {
       var service = this;
       var movies;
       service.getMovies = function() {
           return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/54jf7')
       }
 }]);
```

catch the promise in the controller using `then`

```
datatransfer.getMovies().then(function(response) {
    $scope.movies = response.data;
    $scope.loaded = true;
});
```

Comment: Yeah, ''then'' is supposed to be used with $promise that is being returned by $http.get(...).

Comment: @Kunal Tyagi nice. make sure to check the answer if this helped :D

Comment: @Sachila, this only helped. Can you please tell me where was I wrong?

Comment: `success` and `then` both use to catch promise from the response. so you can use `then` only in the controller to catch the promise

Comment: Is there any way, I can store those values in my movies variable in the service itself?